# What is the point of AutoLogin?

Tags: cakephp, cookies, session-cookies, autologin

[Miles Johnson](http://milesj.me/) just updated his [CakePHP AutoLogin Plugin](https://github.com/milesj/cake-auto_login), and although I am grateful for his work and contributions, I seem to miss the point: what is the difference, or why is it better than just having a long duration session cookie set by **CakePHP**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well lets see here, the AutoLogin script remembers the users login information for x amount of time. You can set this cookie for a year if you want, do you really want to do that for a session? And lastly, this gives the user the option of wanting to stay persistently logged in. I am not aware of a way to do that with extended session times.

Comment: well thanks for coming in yourself! but actually, that's the part I don't get: why would I not want to have a one year session? As for the option to want it or not, I wish to do that automatically without giving the user a choice (they can still logout though).

Comment: I don't agree with that concept. The user shouldn't have to rely on them manually logging out if they don't want persistent login. Their session should die with the browser closing.

Comment: I see your point. Can you think of any other technical and/or security issues to consider?

Comment: @damusnet Shared computer at local cafeteria, not so geeky person and network down. Add those and next guy coming in will steal his beloved kitten and reserves hotel room for him...

Answer (score 0):

that is exactly what it does, https://github.com/milesj/cake-auto_login/blob/master/controllers/components/auto_login.php#L202

also does this over and above just a long running cookie

- **Requires no installation** except for adding the checkbox into your user login forms
- Automatically saves the cookie and info when a user logs in
- Automatically kills the cookie and session when a user logs out
- Inserts a hash within the cookie **so that it cannot be hijacked**
- Encrypts the cookie so the **information cannot be harvested**
- **Configuration options** for cookie name and length
- Functionality for additional user updating or **error logging**

Comment: so you agree, I don't need it if I just set CakePHP's session cookie to a very very long expiration date? Then I'm back to guessing why I could need the plugin...

Comment: because it does a bunch of other things, like stopping session hijacking that your one line long expiring solution offers.

Comment: Also PHP/Apache installs can have a maximum session lifetime that overrides anything you set in your app, for the default session store. Just setting a long expiration date won't work in that case hence using cookie storage instead.

Comment: I seem to be missing how including some more redundantly hashed values in the cookie is supposed to stave off session hijacking. If the cookie is hijacked in its entirety, including the hash value, it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: me too. Also Cake already does HTTP_USER_AGENT check so you'd have to steal the cookie and impersonate the browser. And I have full control over PHP/Apache (or Nginx) settings. Any other points maybe? Thanks for the interesting debate however!